# Using SQL - To Select Xth largest from unique combination of columns

Tags: mysql, sql, database, filtering

I have been stuck at this query for while. I have data table with following structure:

```
 my_tbl:
 -------------------
     id: primary_key
   time: datetime
  asset: int  (number of in-game asset)
   data: char (data generated through in-game asset)
version: int  (version of the asset)
```

Now, from the table I would like to query for data for each unique time for Xth largest version.

I have already developed query to obtain the data for each asset and for each unique time where version is the largest.

Here is my query:

```
SELECT `asset`, `time`, `data`, `version` FROM `my_tbl`
INNER JOIN (
  SELECT MAX(version) as max_iter, `time` as t FROM `my_tbl`
  GROUP BY time
) AS B
ON (B.t = my_tbl.time AND B.max_iter = my_tbl.version) 
ORDER BY asset ASC;
```

Now I can't figure out how to get the second largest and so on....

Here is my data set:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `my_tbl` (
  `id` int unsigned NOT NULL,
  `time` DATETIME NOT NULL,
  `asset` int NOT NULL,
  `data` DECIMAL(7,2) NOT NULL,
  `version` int NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
INSERT INTO `my_tbl` (`id`, `time`, `asset`, `data`, `version`) VALUES
  ( 1, '2017-11-01 10:00:00',1,   7.32, 1),
  ( 2, '2017-11-01 11:00:00',1,  10.32, 1),
  ( 3, '2017-11-01 12:00:00',1,   7.4 , 1),
  ( 4, '2017-11-01 11:00:00',1,   4.3 , 2),
  ( 5, '2017-11-01 12:00:00',1,   4.4 , 2),
  ( 6, '2017-11-01 13:00:00',1,   4.6 , 2),
  ( 7, '2017-11-01 12:00:00',1,   8.3 , 3),
  ( 8, '2017-11-01 13:00:00',1,   8.4 , 3),
  ( 9, '2017-11-01 14:00:00',1,   8.6 , 3),
  (10, '2017-11-01 13:00:00',1,   9.3 , 4),
  (11, '2017-11-01 14:00:00',1,   9.4 , 4),
  (12, '2017-11-01 15:00:00',1,   9.6 , 4),
  (13, '2017-11-01 10:00:00',2,  70   , 1),
  (14, '2017-11-01 11:00:00',2, 100   , 1),
  (15, '2017-11-01 12:00:00',2,  74   , 1),
  (16, '2017-11-01 11:00:00',2,  43   , 2),
  (17, '2017-11-01 12:00:00',2,  44   , 2),
  (18, '2017-11-01 13:00:00',2,  46   , 2),
  (19, '2017-11-01 12:00:00',2,  83   , 3),
  (20, '2017-11-01 13:00:00',2,  84   , 3),
  (21, '2017-11-01 14:00:00',2,  86   , 3),
  (22, '2017-11-01 13:00:00',2,  93   , 4),
  (23, '2017-11-01 14:00:00',2,  94   , 4),
  (24, '2017-11-01 15:00:00',2,  96   , 4),
  (25, '2017-11-01 15:00:00',3,  96   , 4);
```

And here is the link to fiddle that finds the largest:

https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/ggyHLAzbLpWNWwVNaZPJuM/2

Results should look like this for (2)nd largest:

```
+----+---------------------+-------+--------+---------+
| id | time                | asset | data   | version |
+----+---------------------+-------+--------+---------+
|  1 | 2017-11-01 10:00:00 |     1 |   7.32 |       1 |
|  4 | 2017-11-01 11:00:00 |     1 |   4.30 |       2 |
|  5 | 2017-11-01 12:00:00 |     1 |   4.40 |       2 |
|  8 | 2017-11-01 13:00:00 |     1 |   8.40 |       3 |
| 11 | 2017-11-01 14:00:00 |     1 |   9.40 |       4 |
| 12 | 2017-11-01 15:00:00 |     1 |   9.60 |       4 |
| 13 | 2017-11-01 10:00:00 |     2 |  70.00 |       1 |
| 16 | 2017-11-01 11:00:00 |     2 |  43.00 |       2 |
| 17 | 2017-11-01 12:00:00 |     2 |  44.00 |       2 |
| 20 | 2017-11-01 13:00:00 |     2 |  84.00 |       3 |
| 23 | 2017-11-01 14:00:00 |     2 |  94.00 |       4 |
| 24 | 2017-11-01 15:00:00 |     2 |  96.00 |       4 |
| 25 | 2017-11-01 15:00:00 |     3 |  96.00 |       4 |
```

Comment: Why id data VARCHAR? :-(

Comment: Also, I'm confused. Several assets seem to share the same iteration (or 'version').

Comment: @Strawberry yea assets can have same version for different time. so asset a can have version v for 10, 11, 12 am and so on.

Comment: So let's say X = 3, can you edit the question to show what the result set would look like?

Comment: I did it for 2nd largest (X=2) @Strawberry

Comment: There is no second largest for time = '10'. Is that why you select the first one?

Comment: @Strawberry yes!

Comment: Also, I think you meant id = 5 instead of 7

Comment: you are correct - thank you @Strawberry

Answer (score 0):

Before attempting to answer, I think your description and your data set don't match. If the description is correct, then I would anticipate the following result:

```
+----+---------------------+-------+--------+---------+
| id | time                | asset | data   | version |
+----+---------------------+-------+--------+---------+
|  1 | 2017-11-01 10:00:00 |     1 |   7.32 |       1 |
|  4 | 2017-11-01 11:00:00 |     1 |   4.30 |       2 |
|  5 | 2017-11-01 12:00:00 |     1 |   4.40 |       2 |
|  8 | 2017-11-01 13:00:00 |     1 |   8.40 |       3 |
| 11 | 2017-11-01 14:00:00 |     1 |   9.40 |       4 |
| 12 | 2017-11-01 15:00:00 |     1 |   9.60 |       4 |
| 13 | 2017-11-01 10:00:00 |     2 |  70.00 |       1 |
| 16 | 2017-11-01 11:00:00 |     2 |  43.00 |       2 |
| 17 | 2017-11-01 12:00:00 |     2 |  44.00 |       2 |
| 20 | 2017-11-01 13:00:00 |     2 |  84.00 |       3 |
| 23 | 2017-11-01 14:00:00 |     2 |  94.00 |       4 |
| 24 | 2017-11-01 15:00:00 |     2 |  96.00 |       4 |
| 25 | 2017-11-01 15:00:00 |     3 |  96.00 |       4 |
```

Assuming that's correct, then I think this will return what you're after...

```
SELECT m.*
  FROM my_tbl m
  JOIN
     ( SELECT a.time
            , a.asset
            , MAX(a.version) version
         FROM
            ( SELECT time
                   , asset
                   , version
                   , CASE WHEN @time = time
                          THEN CASE WHEN @asset = asset
                                    THEN @i:=@i+1 ELSE @i:=1 END
                                    ELSE @i:=1 END i
                   , @time :=time
                   , @asset := asset
                FROM my_tbl
                   , (SELECT @time:=null, @asset:=null,@i:=0) vars
               ORDER
                  BY time
                   , asset
                   , version
             ) a
         WHERE i <= 2
         GROUP
            BY time, asset
     ) n
    ON n.time = m.time
   AND n.asset = m.asset
   AND n.version = m.version
 ORDER 
    BY m.id;
```

This assumes a natural key on (time,asset,version)

EDIT:

For i <= 3, we would expect the following result (desired rows highlighted with '<--'...

```
SELECT * FROM my_tbl ORDER BY time, asset, version;
+----+---------------------+-------+--------+---------+
| id | time                | asset | data   | version |
+----+---------------------+-------+--------+---------+
|  1 | 2017-11-01 10:00:00 |     1 |   7.32 |       1 |<--

| 13 | 2017-11-01 10:00:00 |     2 |  70.00 |       1 |<--

|  2 | 2017-11-01 11:00:00 |     1 |  10.32 |       1 |
|  4 | 2017-11-01 11:00:00 |     1 |   4.30 |       2 |<--

| 14 | 2017-11-01 11:00:00 |     2 | 100.00 |       1 |
| 16 | 2017-11-01 11:00:00 |     2 |  43.00 |       2 |<--

|  3 | 2017-11-01 12:00:00 |     1 |   7.40 |       1 |
|  5 | 2017-11-01 12:00:00 |     1 |   4.40 |       2 |
|  7 | 2017-11-01 12:00:00 |     1 |   8.30 |       3 |<--

| 15 | 2017-11-01 12:00:00 |     2 |  74.00 |       1 |
| 17 | 2017-11-01 12:00:00 |     2 |  44.00 |       2 |
| 19 | 2017-11-01 12:00:00 |     2 |  83.00 |       3 |<--

|  6 | 2017-11-01 13:00:00 |     1 |   4.60 |       2 |
|  8 | 2017-11-01 13:00:00 |     1 |   8.40 |       3 |
| 10 | 2017-11-01 13:00:00 |     1 |   9.30 |       4 |<--

| 18 | 2017-11-01 13:00:00 |     2 |  46.00 |       2 |
| 20 | 2017-11-01 13:00:00 |     2 |  84.00 |       3 |
| 22 | 2017-11-01 13:00:00 |     2 |  93.00 |       4 |<--

|  9 | 2017-11-01 14:00:00 |     1 |   8.60 |       3 |
| 11 | 2017-11-01 14:00:00 |     1 |   9.40 |       4 |<--

| 21 | 2017-11-01 14:00:00 |     2 |  86.00 |       3 |
| 23 | 2017-11-01 14:00:00 |     2 |  94.00 |       4 |<--

| 12 | 2017-11-01 15:00:00 |     1 |   9.60 |       4 |<--

| 24 | 2017-11-01 15:00:00 |     2 |  96.00 |       4 |<--

| 25 | 2017-11-01 15:00:00 |     3 |  96.00 |       4 |<--
+----+---------------------+-------+--------+---------+
```

And indeed, substituting 'i <= 3' for 'i <= 2' returns this result set.

Comment: I ran this code but unfortunately I cannot do 3rd largest or so on. I replaced `i<=2` to `i<=3` and so on.

Comment: Works fine for me!

Comment: Oh when I meant 3rd largest I want to go from max to 3rd max so in your example: For 11 AM, id of 2 should be selected instead of 4. As it is not the max but 3rd from the max of version: [1, 2]

Comment: You can always order time descendingly, if that's what you're after.

Answer (score 0):

If the dbms you use supports ROW_NUMBER() OVER() then I would use that.

```
SELECT *
FROM (
      SELECT
            , asset
            , time
            , data
            , version 
            , row_number() over(partition by Time order by asset DESC) as RowNumber
      FROM my_tbl
     ) d
WHERE RowNumber = 3
;
```

If you are on a version of MySQL that doesn't support that then I would do this:

```
SELECT *
FROM (
      SELECT
              @row_num :=IF(@prev_value=`time`,@row_num+1,1)AS RowNumber
            , `asset`
            , `time`
            , `data`
            , `version` 
            , @prev_value := `time`
      FROM `my_tbl`
      CROSS JOIN (
                  SELECT @row_num :=1,  @prev_value :=''
                  ) vars
      ORDER BY
              `time`
            , `asset` DESC
     ) d
WHERE RowNumber = 3
;
```

Now you should be able to locate Nth largest asset at any point in time.

NOTE: because you are working with date/time and that can precise to milliseconds you may need to "truncate" the time to a larger time unit (such as hour like we see in your sample data)

---

nb; if your dbms supports DENSE_RANK() OVER() then using that may be a better solution as it will return "equal second" or "equal third" etc. but row_number() will not do that.